# how to open a single tabhost tab in youtube application or in external browser in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, browser, youtube, android-tabhost

i am using tabhost in my android studio and all my tabs are written like this

```
                /************* TAB4 ************/


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Tour.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab8").setIndicator("TOUR")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);


    /************* TAB5 ************/


    intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Blog.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab9").setIndicator("BLOG")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

etc. .....

now i want ONE specific tab to open in the youtube application (if installed) or open in the default browser (if youtube is not installed on android device)

i have found a little bit of code to open the web browser using intent but im not sure how to implement it in to my code or add/call the youtube application feature.....

here is the intent to open a link in a browser

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

my first question is how do i implement this browser code in to my tabs?
cause i figure that out at least i can open links in the browser (which is more important cause i can use it on more the one link)...

my second question is how do i implement calling the youtube application BEFORE trying to call the browser? so the tab would try to open the link in youtube first and then in the browser second if youtube is not installed

basically... 
how do i mix these two codes together?

```
intent = new Intent().setClass(this, Blog.class);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab9").setIndicator("BLOG")
            .setContent(intent);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```

and

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.stackoverflow.com"));
startActivity(intent);
```

would make

```
 ?????
```

Answer (score 0):

turns out by adding http://youtube.com in the link it puts the option to open in youtube if you have it installed

here is the current code im using!

```
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4rWuj3mdfAtHqyufMu57C9LK8By9M_sy"));
    String title = getResources().getString(R.string.chooser_title);
    Intent chooser = Intent.createChooser(intent, title);
    spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab3").setIndicator("VIDEOS")
            .setContent(chooser);
    tabHost.addTab(spec);
```